# list of threads that are started when bash is opened

Tags: multithreading, bash, pthreads

when bash process is started, which threads are created at that moment.
A list of active threads. & 
A list of passive threads, that are waiting for events to occur in order to become active

Comment: this `ps -T -p $$` will give you the threads for the current bash process.

Comment: `bash` is free software, so study its source code. AFAIK it is a single-threaded application

Comment: $(ps -T -p $$) this only giving me only spid. I want to know thread name and purpose.

Comment: I took a quick look at the bash source code, a quick grep in the root dir showed no pthread_create at least. But fork() is used e.g. when creating a pipeline, look for e.g. make_child in jobs.c. (bash 4.4 tarball on official GNU site).